# Derivative of Class number of real quadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\Delta$ be a fundamental quadratic discriminant, set $N = |\Delta|$,
and define the Fekete polynomials 
$$ F_N(X) = \sum_{a=1}^N \Big(\frac{\Delta}a\Big) X^a. $$
Define 
$$ f_N(X) = \frac{F_N(X)}{X^N-1}. $$
 Canceling common factors it can be shown that 
$$ f_N(X) = \frac{H_N(X)}{\Phi_N(X)}, $$
where $\Phi_N$ is the $N$-th cyclotomic polynomial and $H$ has integral
coefficients. (These definitions seem rather ad hoc, but in fact the objects
above are all quite "natural".)

If $\Delta < 0$, then $f_N(1) = \frac{2h}w$, where $h$ is the class
number of $\Delta$ and $w$ the number of roots of unity in the 
corresponding quadratic number fields. In fact we get
$$ f_N(1) = - \frac{\sum_{a=1}^{N-1}  a \Big( \frac{\Delta}a\Big)}N . $$

If $\Delta > 0$, then $f_N(1) = 0$, which suggests looking at the 
first derivative. Here we find that $f_N'(1)$ is always even, so we 
set $f_N'(1) = - 2 h$ and get
$$ h = \frac{\sum_{a=1}^{N-1} 
          \frac{a(a-1)}2 \Big( \frac{\Delta}a\Big)}N . $$
Here is a small table:
$ $ $ \begin{array} {c|ccccccccccc}
    N & 12 & 13 & 17 & 21 & 24 & 28 & 29 & 33 & 37 & 41 & 44 \\ \hline 
    h & 1  & 1  & 2  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 7  \end{array} $

It is quite remarkable that $h$ seems to possess, for positive
discriminants, properties analogous to class numbers. In particular,
$h$ is odd if and only if $\Delta = p > 5$ is a prime $\equiv 5 \bmod 8$,
and if $\Delta$ is divisible by $n$ distinct primes,
then $h$ is divisible by $2^{n-2}$ etc.

In the case $\Delta < 0$, Hasse and Bergström have shown how to 
extract the "genus factor" from the analytic class number formula,
but the necessary calculations were horrible. Thus if we want to 
avoid going through similar technicalities in the case $\Delta > 0$
then we would need a natural interpretation of $h$ as the order of
an analogue of a "class group".

So I guess my question is whether there is such a mysterious 
group (connected to real quadratic number fields) with order $h$.
Even a proof that $h \ne 0$ would be welcome, since in the case of 
negative discriminants this is equivalent to the nonvanishing of 
Dirichlet's L-function at $s = 1$.

**Edit.** As Rene Schoof has pointed out, the numbers in question
are essentially generalized Bernoulli numbers $B_{2,\chi}$ for
(quadratic) Dirichlet characters with conductor $N$. These numbers
are defined by
$$ B_{2,\chi} = \sum_{a=1}^N \chi(a) B_2(a/N), $$
where $B_2(X) = X^2 - X + \frac16$ is the second Bernoulli polynomial.
The constant term $\frac 16$, in which this expression differs from the
one I have used above, is irrelevant since $\sum \chi(a) = 0$.

These numbers $B_{2,\chi}$ show up as factors of eigenspaces of cuspidal 
divisor class groups as studied in the book by Kubert-Lang (more exactly,
the $p$-part of the group is reflected in the divisibility by $p$ of the
Bernoulli numbers). The Birch-Tate-Lichtenbaum conjecture also
predicts that the $B_{2,\chi}$ are factors of $K_2({\mathcal O})$,
where ${\mathcal O}$ is the ring of integers of the maximal real
subfield of the $N$-th roots of unity (Kubert-Lang, p. 151).

Although these numbers have such a prominent place in number theory, 
their elementary properties apparently have not been investigated 
(I've looked into Washington's and Lang's books on cyclotomic number 
fields). Numerical experiments suggest e.g. the following:

Let $\chi$ be an even Dirichlet character with conductor $N$. 
Then $h_2(N) = \frac{N}4 B_{2,\chi}$ is an integer for all $N > 8$.
Moreover, $h_2(N)$ is odd if and only if

1. $N = p$ for primes $p \not \equiv 1 \bmod 8$;
2. $N = 4p$ for primes $p \equiv 3 \bmod 8$;
3. $N = 8p$ for odd primes $p \not \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 8$.

In absence of any kind of genus theory for cuspidal divisor class groups 
it seems that the only option for proving such results is working
directly with the definition of these numbers. As mentioned above,
this becomes technical for integers with many prime factors.

There are similar results for  $h_3(N) = \frac{N^2}6 B_{3,\chi}$,
and there can be no doubt that most of this generalizes in some 
form to all generalized Bernoulli numbers $B_{n,\chi}$.

This whole set of question came out of my approach to quadratic reciprocity 
in Chapter 7 of my notes on 
[Pell conics](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/pell.html).

Comment: Hi!  I think these are generalized Bernoulli numbers $B_{2,\chi}$
associated the quadratic character $\chi$ of conductor $\Delta$.
Apart from a power of $2$ perhaps, they are equal to the order
of the $\chi$-part of the cuspidal divisor class group of the modular curve $X_1(\Delta)$. See the book by Kubert-Lang for more details.